# Calculate mean values in a quadratic curve

Tags: r, mean, quadratic

Here's a sample data

```
 sales <- function(price) { 100 - 0.5 * price }
 x <- 50:150
 x1 <- sales(x)
 revenue <- function(price) { price * sales(price) }
 y<- revenue(x)

 dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(y,x))
 plot(dat$y ~ dat$x)
```

[image]

I want to calculate 2 means of `y`:

(1) Mean 1: mean of `y` starting the first value of `x` till `y` reaches the maximum value (in the middle).

(2) Mean 2: mean of `y` from the maximum value till it reaches the minimum value at the last value of `x`.

I thought I will sort out the data first according to increasing x-values

```
dat1 <- dat[order(dat$x),]
```

But I am stuck here. I am not sure how do I calculate the two means from here?

Comment: `dfchunk <- split(dat, factor(sort(rank(row.names(dat))%%n)))` which `n = 2`

Comment: I guess you've been around enough to know this but for the reference: [Why accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `split` function:

```
n <- 2
dfchunk <- split(dat1, factor(sort(rank(row.names(dat1))%%n)))
```

This will give you a list of 2.

Then you can get the mean for each of them:

```
avgYFirstHalf  <- mean(dfchunk$`0`$y)
avgYSecondHalf <- mean(dfchunk$`1`$y)

> avgYFirstHalf
# 4570.75
> avgYSecondHalf 
# 4579.167
```